# SQL `IN` not work in Spring Boot when using JDBCTemplate

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've JDBC template object and I try run query to database for delete but I can't run this query. How can I do it?

```
jdbcTemplate.update("delete from `message` where `id` IN (:ids) and `from` = ?;", new Integer[] {1, 2}, 1);
```

--- ADDED

```
public static final Map<String, String> SQL = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
        put("removeMessages", "delete from `message` where `id` IN ( :ids ) and `@` = :userId ;");
    }};


    public int removeMessages(@NonNull Integer[] ids, @NonNull Integer userId, boolean asSender) {
        MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("ids", Arrays.asList(ids)).addValue("userId", userId);
        String sql = SQL.get("removeMessages").replace("@", asSender ? "from" : "to");
        return getInstance(MainSQL.class).query(sql, parameters);
    }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate what error you're getting

Comment: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [delete from `message` where `id` IN (:ids) and `from` = :userId ;]; Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use  NamedParameterJdbcTemplate for named parameters.
Try to use this code:

```
List<Integer> ids= Arrays.asList(1,2);
MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
parameters.addValue("ids", ids);
parameters.addValue("from",1);
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update("delete from `message` where `id` IN (:ids) and `from` = :from;",parameters);
```

Comment: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [delete from `message` where `id` IN (:ids) and `from` = :userId ;]; Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

Comment: Named parameter is called from but you are suing userId

Comment: I added example to main post. Look it please

Comment: Why dont simple not execute code from my example ? What benefit replacing gives you ?

Comment: Your code don't work. Exception: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [delete from `message` where `id` IN ( :ids ) and `from` = :from ;]; Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

Comment: You are using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate ?

Comment: Please share full example of class where you are using namedJdbcTemplate

Comment: Thanks for that )